# Android banner ads not displaying in Listview as expected

Tags: android, android-listview, admob

I'm attempting to create a listview which has banner ads at every nth interval. In my code, it's every 6 items. I've based my code on the example [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-adcatalog/blob/master/adcatalog/src/com/google/ad/catalog/layouts/ListViewExampleListAdapter.java).  The example provided is based on having a banner ad at the first and last of the listview, so I've encountered problems when trying to intersperse the banner ads within the listview at equal intervals. Specifically, my ads don't display every 6th time. The result I have from the code below is displaying two consecutive ads at positions 7,8 and then my third at position 13. I'm not sure what could be causing the ad at position 8 to appear.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Code below...

Firstly, the creation of my SimpleCursorAdapter, which contains about 14 strings to display in the listview in this case.

```
// Create and populate listview 
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

// SimpleCursorAdapter method
Cursor c = dbh.getAllCategoriesCursor();
startManagingCursor(c);

String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.category_label};

// Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, c, from, to, 0);

setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this, cursorAdapter));
```

And here is my ListViewAdapter, extending the BaseAdapter class

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity mContext;  
    private SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter;  
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;  
    private int k = 6; // interval ad every 6 items
    int baseItems;
    int noAds; // used for listview offset

    // Constructor takes in a BaseAdapter 
    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, SimpleCursorAdapter delegate) {
        mContext = activity;  
        listAdapter = delegate; 
        baseItems = listAdapter.getCount();
        noAds  = baseItems / k;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext  
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Total count includes list items and ads.
        return baseItems + noAds;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // Return null if an item is an ad.  Otherwise return the delegate item.
        if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
            return null;
        }
        return listAdapter.getItem(getOffsetPosition(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return listAdapter.getViewTypeCount() + noAds;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
            return listAdapter.getViewTypeCount();
        } else {
            return listAdapter.getItemViewType(getOffsetPosition(position));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return (!isItemAnAd(position)) && listAdapter.isEnabled(getOffsetPosition(position));
    }

    private boolean isItemAnAd(int position) {
        // Place an ad at the first and last list view positions.
        // -- should override for every kth positions
        if (position == 0) return false;
        // Calculate offsets caused by ads already embedded
        int offset = 0;
        if (position > k){
            int div = position / k;
            offset = div;
        }
        return ((position-offset) % k == 0);

    }


    // Get the position that is offset by the insertion of the ads
    private int getOffsetPosition(int position) {

        return position - noAds;

    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Display every n list items
        if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
            if (convertView instanceof AdView) {
                // Don’t instantiate new AdView, reuse old one
                return convertView;
            } else {
                // Create a new AdView
                AdView adView = new AdView(getApplicationContext());
                adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
                adView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_ID);

                // Disable focus for sub-views of the AdView to avoid problems with
                // trackpad navigation of the list.
                for (int i = 0; i < adView.getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                    adView.getChildAt(i).setFocusable(false);
                }
                adView.setFocusable(false);

                // Convert the default layout parameters so that they play nice with
                // ListView.

                float density = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
                AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                        AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        height);
                adView.setLayoutParams(params);
                AdRequest bannerIntermediateReq = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("d9e108ab") //means that a test ad is shown on my phone
                .build();

                adView.loadAd(bannerIntermediateReq);

                return adView;
            }
        } else {

            // Offload displaying other items to the delegate 
            return listAdapter.getView(position - (int) Math.ceil(position / k),
                    convertView, parent);

        }
    }
}
```

Update 9/6... Found a workaround of sorts that creates an ad at the nth interval, followed by all following ads at n-1 intervals. So if I set n=8 I'll get an ad inserted after 8 list items, after ads inserted every 7 items after that. I'm quite happy to settle for this given the amount of time I've sunk into it. It's probably an off-by-one bug somewhere that I cannot find whatsoever. Hope this helps someone at some point. Here's the modifications:

```
private boolean isItemAnAd(int position) {


        if (position < k) return false;
        // Calculate current offset caused by ads already embedded

        if (position==k){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return isItemAnAd(position-k);
        }


    }
```

and

```
// Get the position that is offset by the insertion of the ads
        private int getOffsetPosition(int position) {
            int currentNoAds = position / k;
            return position - currentNoAds;

        }
```

and, in getView...

```
return listAdapter.getView(getOffsetPosition(position) ,
                        convertView, parent);
```